# Bind a List<Group> to ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, data-binding

I have a following XAML:

```
<ComboBox 
 Name="groupComboBox" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyServiceMap.Groups}"
 DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Name}"/>
```

In the code behind i set this.DataContext to my viewModel.

```
private ServiceMap _serviceMap;
    public ServiceMap MyServiceMap
    {
        get
        {
            return _serviceMap;
        }
        set
        {
            _serviceMap = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyServiceMap");
        }
    }
```

My ServiceMap class is

```
public class ServiceMap
{
    //other code
    public List<Group> Groups = new List<Group>();
}
```

and finally:

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. How can i bind combobox to show Group Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First is bindings are only work on properties, so the binding couldn't find the Group field. Change it to a property.

```
public class ServiceMap
{
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

The second one is that the DisplayMemberPath waits for a string not a binding. Change it simply to "Name".

```
<ComboBox Name="groupComboBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyServiceMap.Groups}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: Tnx its working. I replaced it with a Name, but left List<Group> as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DisplayMemberPath="Name"?